# EC2 Key-pair information works on one server but not another

Tags: amazon-ec2, pem

I had a key-pair for one server which has been working for a few years. I created a new server today and asked it to use the same key-pair information. I verified in the console that both are using the same key-pair information.

I can `ssh` into my new server using the pem file. So I know that the pem file is not corrupted. But, I cannot `ssh` into my old server anymore.

The error is: `Permission denied (publickey).`

I still happen to have read access to my old server (I have a tab open which is ssh'ed in), but don't seem to have write access.

What could cause this problem and how could I resolve it?

FYI, `.ssh/authorized_keys` still seems to contain a public key associated with this pem file. This public key is identical on both servers.

Update:
I'm 99% sure the user is correct. I'm using `ubuntu`. This is the user that I see in the ssh window I have open from before. Also, when I try to login as root, I get the error: `Please login as the user "ubuntu" rather than the user "root".`

Update #2:

Here's the output of ssh with -vvv

```
$ ssh -i privateKey.pem ubuntu@ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com -vvv
OpenSSH_7.5p1, LibreSSL 2.5.4
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/USERNAME/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 52: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com [XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file privateKey.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file privateKey.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.5
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:22 as 'ubuntu'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/USERNAME/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /Users/USERNAME/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: ecdh-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:y6JMkm+4kp5sV9GLZYj0xUKIVSiUXBktG9MxyfnDmxI
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/USERNAME/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /Users/USERNAME/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from ec2-184-169-151-249.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/USERNAME/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /Users/USERNAME/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 184.169.151.249
debug1: Host 'ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/USERNAME/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug2: key: privateKey.pem (0x0), explicit
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: privateKey.pem
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:lbgZZp6+4mYEkpoSzvdzajq0K/c5tIm83noZ6ZDL5hE
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: Can you add `-vvv` option to `ssh` to your old server and post the output?

Comment: I wonder if it's related to `debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory`?

Comment: The `debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory` thing is normal

Answer (score 1):

I guess you accidentally changed the permission of the file `/home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys`. I have reproduced the error. According to AWS, `/home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys` must be limited to the owner only.

If you have logged out, Then you have two ways to solve this.

**Method 1:** Stop your instance, click `Actions->Instance Settings->View/Change User Data` to add the following User Data and then start the instance

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="//"
MIME-Version: 1.0

--//
Content-Type: text/cloud-config; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cloud-config.txt"

#cloud-config
cloud_final_modules:
- [scripts-user, always]

--//
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="userdata.txt"

#!/bin/bash
chmod 600 /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 700 /home/ubuntu/.ssh
chmod 700 /home/ubuntu
--//
```

**Method 2:** you can launch a debug instance. Then stop your old server and mount the root volume of your old server to the debug instance, and run the following commands to set the correct permission:

```
[ubuntu ~]chmod 600 mount_point/home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys
[ubuntu ~]chmod 700 mount_point/home/ubuntu/.ssh
[ubuntu ~]chmod 700 mount_point/home/ubuntu
```

It it doesn't work, you could following the steps to troubleshoot your instance: [Error: Host key not found, Permission denied (publickey), or Authentication failed, permission denied](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html)

Comment: Ah, damn. I just lost access. This looks promising though. I'll give the chmod command a try tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: I added a new solution to user data to solve this. It is easy to use and I tested using my instance and it works.

Comment: Hmmmm...sadly, the user data version didn't work. Since I managed to migrate my server, I think I'm just going to create a new instance with this disk image. Probably the fastest way to resolve this.

Comment: Thanks for the help though. Hopefully, it'll help someone else in the future.